# ExpandableListView populate from raw

Tags: android, expandablelistview, populate

I can do nothing to populate my Expandable List. I want to make child items clickable and after click - you go to another activity, where you can see an information of the child.
So, I know how to do this with List View, but not with the Expandable. (E.G. [look there](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/crib.php)). There this is realized by text files (.txt) which is located in res/raw. I really need to do that. HELP PLEASE! I'm waiting for the SAVIOR! :)

So, there my there my Expandable List. (this is also from [there](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/))

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Открыт",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

 // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Закрыт",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Part 1.");
    listDataHeader.add("Part 2.");
    listDataHeader.add("Part 3.");
    listDataHeader.add("Part 4.");
    listDataHeader.add("Part 5.");
    listDataHeader.add("Part 6.");
    listDataHeader.add("Part 7.");
    listDataHeader.add("Part 8.");
    listDataHeader.add("Ending");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> raz1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz1.add("Chapter 1.");
    raz1.add("Chapter 2.");
    raz1.add("Chapter 3.");
    raz1.add("Chapter 4.");
    raz1.add("Chapter 5. 47-49) Таможенная статистика");
    raz1.add("Chapter 6.");
    raz1.add("Chapter 7.");
    raz1.add("Chapter 8.");

    List<String> raz2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz2.add("Chapter 9.");
    raz2.add("Chapter 10.");
    raz2.add("Chapter 11.");
    raz2.add("Chapter 12.");
    raz2.add("Chapter 13.");
    raz2.add("Chapter 14.");

    List<String> raz3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz3.add("Chapter 15.");
    raz3.add("Chapter 16.");
    raz3.add("Chapter 17.");
    raz3.add("Chapter 18.");
    raz3.add("Chapter 19.");
    raz3.add("Chapter 20.");
    raz3.add("Chapter 21.");

    List<String> raz4 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz4.add("Chapter 22.");
    raz4.add("Chapter 23.");
    raz4.add("Chapter 24.");
    raz4.add("Chapter 25.");

    List<String> raz5 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz5.add("Chapter 26.");
    raz5.add("Chapter 27.");
    raz5.add("Chapter 28.");

    List<String> raz6 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz6.add("Chapter 29.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 30.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 31.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 32.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 33.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 34.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 35.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 36.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 37.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 38.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 39.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 40.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 41.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 42.");
    raz6.add("Chapter 43.");

    List<String> raz7 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz7.add("Chapter 44.");
    raz7.add("Chapter 45.");
    raz7.add("Chapter 46.");
    raz7.add("Chapter 47.");
    raz7.add("Chapter 48.");
    raz7.add("Chapter 49.");
    raz7.add("Chapter 50.");

    List<String> raz8 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz8.add("After");

    List<String> raz9 = new ArrayList<String>();
    raz9.add("The end");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), raz1); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), raz2);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), raz3);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), raz4); 
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), raz5);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), raz6);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), raz7); 
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), raz8);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(8), raz9);

}

}
```

Comment: Why can't you write a custom adapter?? It will solve your problems.

Comment: For Jithu :)
Yeah, of course it's good to write another adapter, but I really like this adapter because it's very comfortable and perfect for my application . And of course I believe that if someone answer for my question - it will a great solution for many people. 
But if you have some adapter' codes that can help to realize the aims, it will be great if you share with us :)